# (Date) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into CategoryModel.createdDate

Tags: java, rest, date

While working on model class i face an following warning :--

```
com.model.products.CategoryModel.setCreatedDate(Date) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into CategoryModel.createdDate
```

My model Class

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class CategoryModel {

     private Date createdDate;

     public Date getCreatedDate() {

        return createdDate;

//Warning Message:--com.model.products.CategoryModel.getCreatedDate(Date) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into CategoryModel.createdDate

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {

        this.createdDate = createdDate;

//Warning Message:--com.model.products.CategoryModel.setCreatedDate(Date) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into CategoryModel.createdDate

}
```

Description of the warning:--

**Returning a reference to a mutable object value stored in one of the object's fields exposes the internal representation of the object.  If instances are accessed by untrusted code, and unchecked changes to the mutable object would compromise security or other important properties, you will need to do something different. Returning a new copy of the object is better approach in many situations.**

In above model class i get an warning , what is the better approach to handle this ?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you use `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime`?

Comment: While depreciated, it's still possible for `Date` to be changed (mutated) externally, which could have unforeseen consequences on your model, where as the `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` classes can't be (they return a new object)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  so you mean to say that i use LocalDate/LocalDateTime insted of date.

Comment: I don't have enough context to know if that would be possible, but that would provide a non-mutable representation of the date/time

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok ill try this Thanks a lot..!!!

Comment: `LocalDateTime` purposely loses time zone information. Not likely what you need here. Use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Defensive copy

You are accepting a reference to mutable object from outside your class for use inside your class. That means the source of that mutable object can mutate its value behind your back. One moment your own object contains June 3rd of this year, and a moment later it contains November 27th of last year. And any other objects with a reference to that mutable object can mutate its value behind your back in the same tragic manner.

Best practice is to make a defensive copy of that mutable object upon receipt. Copy out its internal values into another fresh object. You know this fresh object is safe as no other objects have a reference to it.

If you do not understand this behavior of object references in Java, study some basics about Java programming. Perhaps the Oracle.com Tutorials, or the Head First book on Java by the O’Reilly publisher.

An alternative to defensive copy is to use an immutable object in the first place. If immutable, the entire issue is eliminated.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

The java.time classes are [immutable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So your problem described above is eliminated if you replace every use of `Date` & `Calendar` with a *java.time* class. For a moment on the timeline in UTC, the same as `java.util.Date`, use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```java
public class CategoryModel {

    // Member fields.
    private Instant created ;

    // Constructor.
    public CategoryModel ( final Instant created ) {  this.created = Objects.requireNonNull( created ) ; } 

    // Getters.
    public Instant getCreated() { return this.created ; }

    // Setters.
    public void setCreated ( final Instant created ) {  this.created = Objects.requireNonNull( created ) ; }

}
```

Usage when interfacing with legacy code.

```
CategoryModel cm = new CategoryModel ( myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ) ;
```

And:

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = Date.from( cm.getCreated() ) ;
```

Comment: so you means to say that i use   private Instant createdDate; instead of private Date createdDate;   ???

Comment: @h36p Yes. You can even keep the same method signature, accepting the Date then converting it to an Instant. This approach uses both my points, defensive copy *and* immutable object.  `private Instant whenCreated ;` and `this.whenCreated = passedUtilDate.toInstant() ; ` But best to avoid those legacy classes wherever possible, using java.time throughout your code base.